# Beginner html ques :: How to get horizontal scroll bars to appear? they just won't..the data in the td tag is moving on to the next line

Tags: html, css

I want the text to appear in one single line..td actually contains text and drop down list controls...Also its a table within another td tag

I have tried changing everything..alignment, width..what not

but the text moves to the next line instead of appearing on the same line..I want the horizontal bars to appear..what value should I give to the width attribute of table ?

hope the question isnt confusing :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying this class to td:

```
.scroll{
  overflow:auto;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}

<td class="scroll">A lot of content here....</td>
```

Alternatively, you can put a `div` inside the `td` and apply the style to that instead:

```
<td>
   <div class="scroll">A lot of content here....</div>
</td>
```

#### Update

You can apply the inline style like this:

```
<td style="overflow:auto; overflow-x:scroll;">A lot of content here....</td>
```

Comment: Do I HAVE to use CSS .. Is there no other way ? ...like changing some attribute value in the table,td or tr tag ??

Comment: its not working for me..where do I add this style attribute ? I have tried adding it in the table,td,tr,tbody..all the tags..its getting all screwed up..all I want is horizontal bars to appear but the text in the td is moving to the next line..i want it to appear in one single line

Comment: the hierarchy is like this..
[edit]
ok I am not able to show the hierarchy structure here..I tried...

my text is inside a table which is inside another table

where do I add style attribute?

Comment: I found the solution myself ! yay...
This is the attribute that needed to be added :: nowrap="nowrap"

Comment: ok it got screwed up again :((
After adding the no wrap attribute, all the spaces have gone that existed between text and drop down list controls.. I added "nbsp" but it wont give space in between..now what !??

help!!

Comment: ok I have sorted it out..just needed to increase the tr's width
anyways..thnx Sarfraz..learnt something new frm ur answer :)